# Java String replace - non-capturing group captures

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Java code:

```
String initial = "Phone number: [194-582-9412]";
System.out.println(initial.replaceAll("\\d{3}\\-\\d{3}(?=\\-\\d{4})","XXX-XXX"));
System.out.println(initial.replaceAll("\\d{3}\\-\\d{3}(?:\\-\\d{4})","XXX-XXX"));
```

which produces output:

> Phone number: [XXX-XXX-9412]
>   Phone number: [XXX-XXX]

My logic was to find 3 digits, a dash, 3 digits (capturing to this point), a dash, and four digits (non-capturing to this point). According to [this tutorial](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-regular-expressions/regex-lookahead.html), lookahead groups starting with `?=` are non-capturing. According to [the Pattern Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special),  groups beginning with `?:` are also non-capturing. I expected both regular expressions to produce the same output, `Phone number: [XXX-XXX-9412]`. However, the regular expression with the non-capturing group `(?:\\-\\d{4})` seems to capture the entire phone number and replace it. Why is this happening?

Comment: Any reason to not just capture the phone number itself as a group? Seems like a double negative (replacing what you don't want, vs grabbing what you do)

Comment: Lookarounds do not consume characters in the string. A non capturing group does consume characters in the string, but does not create a capturing group. Read about [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [grouping and capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: @Rogue I need phone numbers (which will always be in the same format) to be masked before sending the relevant data part to the user, if they don't have the security credentials for that information. I'm just wondering about the weird behavior of `?:` here, because it was the first option that popped to mind, and it didn't work as expected.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Alright, I think I understand now. The bit about consuming characters (as opposed to capturing group) was most helpful for me.

Comment: It isn't capturing.  But you are replacing everything that matches which includes the non-capturing group.  The reason the first one worked wasn't because it was non-capturing, it was because it's zero-width.

Comment: from the given Javadoc: "Capturing groups are so named because, during a match, each subsequence of the input sequence that matches such a group is saved. The captured subsequence may be used later in the expression, via a back reference, and may also be retrieved from the matcher once the match operation is complete." (since you are not using back reference or retrieving groups from matcher, capturing is not relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do what you wanted using capturing groups.  Here it captures the part you want to keep and replaces the whole string.  The `$1` is a back reference to the capture group.

```java
 System.out.println(
            initial.replaceAll("\\d{3}-\\d{3}(\\-\\d{4})", "XXX-XXX$1"));
```

And I presume you realize that if the `regex` doesn't match, then the original string is returned with no changes.